# Show that $f(x,y)=\dfrac{\sin(x^4-y^4)}{x^2+y^2}$ is steady on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My task is to show that

$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin(x^4-y^4)}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

is steady on $\Bbb{R}$

As a composition of steady functions, it is enough to show that $f(x,y)$ converges to $0$ for $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

I've started with the following:

$$\tag{$\forall(x,y)\ne(0,0)$}x = \cos(\phi)\cdot r$$$$y = \sin(\phi)\cdot r$$

$$f(x,y) = f(\phi, r) = \dfrac{\sin(r^4(cos^4(\phi)-\sin^4(\phi)))}{r^2(\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi))}$$
$$=\dfrac{\sin(r^4(\cos^4(\phi)-\sin^4(\phi)))}{r^2}$$

With $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y)= \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}f(\phi, r)$$

It can be seen that the term converges to $0$ for $r\rightarrow 0$ but I wanted to show this mathematically:

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}f(\phi, r) = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{d f(\phi, r)}{\color{red}{d?}} = \color{red}{?}$$

My question is:

w.r.t which variable would I need to take the derivative in order to do this mathematically correct.

I am very happy for any kind of help or advice.

Greetings, Finn

Comment: What is a *steady*  function?

Comment: It would be $r$, the variable in the limit.

Comment: @Bernard, functions that satisfy convergency to the same value for any x,y no matter if the limit is coming from the top or the bottom.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Thank you!

Comment: @FinnEggers: That explanation didn't really make much sense, but if you mean the German word *stetig*, the English term is *continuous*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** As $r\to0$
$$\dfrac{\sin(r^4(\cos^4(\phi)-\sin^4(\phi)))}{r^2}=\dfrac{\sin(r^4\cos2\phi)}{r^2}<r^2\cos2\phi\to0$$

Comment: Perhaps add in the difference of 2 squares step but I really like this proof otherwise.

Comment: Assuming that I would know all the trigonmetric identities etc., this solution is great.

Comment: Thanks. There is only $\cos^t-\sin^2t=\cos2t$ here.

Answer (score 1):

$|f(x,y)| \le \frac{|x^4-y^4|}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}  \le x^2+y^2$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Well yeah that is really clever!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin(r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi))}{r^2} = \frac{\sin(r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi))}{r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi)}r^2(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi)$$
Of course
$$\lim_{r\to 0}r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi) = 0$$
thus 
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\sin(r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi))}{r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi)}r^2(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi) =\lim_{r\to 0}r^2(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4\phi) = 0 $$

Comment: You assume that you know that $sin(x)/x$ converges to $1$, right?

Comment: @FinnEggers yes.

Comment: lovely solution then :)

Answer (score 1):

To prove $f(r,\phi)$ tends to $0$, just so some trigonometry:
$$\frac{\sin(r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4 \phi ))}{r^2}=\frac{\sin(r^4(\cos^2\phi -\sin^2 \phi ))}{r^2}=\frac{\sin(r^4\cos2\phi)}{r^2}.$$
Now, for all $u$, one has $\;|\sin u|\le |u|$, so
$$\biggl|\frac{\sin(r^4(\cos^4\phi -\sin^4 \phi ))}{r^2}\biggr|\le\frac{r^4|\cos2\phi|}{r^2}\le r^2,$$
which tends to $0$ as $\|(x,y)\|=r$ tends to $0$.